# Issue in understanding the following program

Tags: c, string, enums, character, fgets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 1001 };

    char s[N] = "";

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    const char *delim  = " \t\n";

    for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
    {
        p += strspn( p, delim );

        int n = strcspn( p, delim );

        if ( n ) printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, p );

        p += n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program inputs a string and for every whitespace in between inserts a new line character due to which each word get printed in new line.

I want to know how this for loop and fgets function works.

Answer (score 0):

Both `strspn` and `strcspn` return the number of sequential characters in the `accept` set, or not containing the `reject` set made up of the characters in `delim` -- the `space`, `tab`, `newline` (see [man 3 strspn](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html)). The `for` loop is advancing the pointer `p` that points to a character within `s` to effectively skip whitespace and then count the length of the next sequence of non-whitespace characters. The non-whitespace sequence of characters (`n` characters) are then printed from within the buffer filled by `fgets` starting with the character pointed to by `p`.

Try it, enter the following and and see what is printed.

```
    my       dog     has                 fleas
```

(see [man 3 printf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) for the explanation of `"%*.*s\n"` *format-string*)

As for the construction of the `for` loop itself, a `for` loop is simply a loop with the form `for (init clause; test clause; increment clause)` -- any one of the 3 can be empty. For example `for (;;)` simply loops continually.

In your case `s` is the buffer of `1001` characters that is filled by `fgets()` reading the user-input on `stdin`. The loop:

```
for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
```

Initializes the const character pointer `p` to the first character is `s`. The test of `*p` is simply short-hand for `*p != '\0'` (not at the *nul-character marking the end of the string). There is no increment clause because the pointer `p` is advanced within the loop by:

```
    p += strspn( p, delim );       /* advance p by the number of sequential whitespace chars */
```

and

```
    p += n;                        /* advance p by the number of non-whitespace chars printed */
```

That's pretty much it in a nutshell.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum { N = 1001 };
char s[N] = "";

fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );
```

`fgets()` reads a string until it encounters a newline `\n` (not just white space () or tab (`\t`) or if the number of elements to write to are exceeded.

`s` decays to a pointer to the array of `char` `s`. `sizeof(s)` will give the number of elements in `s`, apparently `N`, which is `1001`. `stdin` is the standard input stream.

---

```
for ( const char *p = s; *p; )
{
    p += strspn( p, delim );

    int n = strcspn( p, delim );

    if ( n ) printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, p );

    p += n;
}
```

`p` is a pointer to a `const char`, here `s`, which means `s` treated as a string or otherwise any elements of it can´t be modified inside of the `for` loop.

`p` get dereferenced, means it will get evaluated to the character `p` actual point to. The loop continues until `p` points to the null character of the string inside `s`.

```
    const char *delim  = " \t\n";

    ....

    p += strspn( p, delim );
```

`p` will get incremented by the number of white space characters, as provided in the string `delim` is pointing to, before the first occurrence of any other (readable) characters in `s`.

```
    int n = strcspn( p, delim );
```

`n` will get the number of characters in `s` read before the first occurrence of any white space characters as provided in the string `delim` is pointing to.

```
    if ( n ) printf( "%*.*s\n", n, n, p );
```

If `n` is non-zero (means if there are any amount of non-white space characters to print before the next white space character), `printf()` will print a sequence of consecutive non-white space characters (an actual word) contained in `s` to which `p` is pointing to. If the string contains several words then each word will printed separately at an explicit line, done in different iterations of the `for` loop.

The first `*` after `%` specifies the minimum field width (How many characters shall be printed) which is provided by `n`. If `p` actually points to a character sequence of less elements than `n`, the left space will be padded with white spaces.

The `.*` specifies the precision (How many characters of the character sequence pointed to by `p` are actually printed.

```
    p += n;
```

`p` will get incremented by the number of characters in `s` read before the first occurrence of any of white space characters.

The loop condition will proof if `*p` is actually pointing to `\0`, which then would evaluate to `0` and the loop will stop. Else it iterates another time through the loop.